# TableViewCell image change when touched

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios5, uitableview

I have my own `TableViewCell` class which **inherit** `UITableViewCell`. On my cell **nib** file, I have put a image in my `TableViewCell`. (The image does not fully occupy the whole cell area, there are spaces around image)

Then, I would like to implement a **touch feedback** feature that when user touch the image in the cell, the image will be replaced by another image.

I tried to do it in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method :

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //my TableViewCell   
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //New image to replace the current one
    UIImage* bg = [CCTheme imageNamed:@"green_btn_bg"];
    UIImageView* bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgView;
    ...
```

But it does not work at all. So, how can I implement this touch feedback feature?? That's when user finger touched the image in cell, the image get changed to another one.

Comment: Do you have an outlet for the `UIImageView` you added in the `xib`? My guess it you should be changing the image of that `imageView` and not the cell's `selectedBackgroundView` property

Comment: Yes I have a outlet, could you please be more specific about under which function should I change the outlet image?

Answer (score 0):

- In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you have to first change your data model (indicate that the status of the cell has changed).
- You set the appropriate image  `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. (I.e. you check what the status is and provide the correct image.)
- To update the cell, call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:`.

**Explanation**

You should not store the state of your cell in some view of the cell. E.g. if the different image represents some kind of selection, your array or other data structure that feeds your table view should keep track of which row is in this state.

Each time the cell has to be regenerated, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called. (This could be because the cell becomes visible, or because you explicitly update it.) This is the best place to check for the state information and display the cell accordingly.

Comment: I only understand your last point, the first 2 are unclear. What do you mean & how to change my data model, what do you mean about set appropriate image & how?? I did already set an appropriate image.

Comment: See the explanation I added above.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `UIImageView` property in your custom `UITableViewCell` class as an `IBOutlet` then set the image on that property from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` rather than the background property.

```
cell.yourCustomImageView.image = bgView;
```

Or add the UIImageView to the current generic UITableViewCell like below.

with your Current cell

```
[cell addSubview:bgView];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend hooking a gesture recognizer to the `UIImageView` within your custom cell's init method:

```
// Add recognizer for tappable image
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];

self.tappableImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.tappableImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Then the handler:

```
- (void)imageViewTapped:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"image tapped");
    self.tappableImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some_different_image.png"];
}
```

Also, don't forget to have you custom cell declaration decorated like so:

```
@interface CustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you need to ensure that the code in your init method is being fired so that the `tapRecognizer` is added.

Good luck!

**[EDIT]**

Depending on how you create your cell with the custom XIB you may not need this, but in my case I needed to explicitly call a method to initialize the state of the UI in the table cell. The way I do this is offer an `initState` method on the custom table view cell:

```
- (void)initState {

    // Do other things for state of the UI in table cell.

    // Add recognizer for tappable image
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewTapped:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];

    self.tappableImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self.tappableImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I make sure to call `initState` on my table cell after it has been created:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        UIViewController *temporaryController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomTableViewCell" bundle:nil];
        // Grab a pointer to the custom cell.
        cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)temporaryController.view;

        [cell initState];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to ensure in cellForRowAtIndexPath method the init method is being fired?

Comment: @Mellon, I added some code that shows how I use a custom XIB and call a custom `initState` method on my cell that hooks up the gesture recognizer.